# Are there any standards to typeset an article with English and Chinese mixed?

Tags: punctuation

Are there any standards to typeset an article with English and Chinese mixed? I have difficulty in using the correct punctuations and space characters. I found a Chinese standard describing the details of mixing Chinese and English, but I want to know if there are any US standard about this topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use English standards in the English part.  Use Chinese standards in the Chinese part.

A possible situation is that a Chinese phrase is quoted in an English paragraph use English quotes around the quote, but Chinese punctuation within it:

> My teacher was fond of proverbs. One day he told me, “子曰：「吾十有五而志于学、三十而立、四十而不惑、五十而知天命、六十而耳顺、七十而从心所欲、不逾矩。」” which is taken from *The Analects* 《论语》.

The English uses normal English puctuation, but the embedded Chinese quote uses Chinese punctuation inside.

Similarly, if you just want to mention single Chinese words in a English text, the punctuation is English:

> In this case you use "其中" instead of "之间".

(I can't say how you'd write that if it was single English words in Chinese text, because then it would follow the style used in Chinese, and this site is about learning English, not Chinese)

This assumes your reader is fluent in both languages.  If your reader is not fluent in both languages then the "foreign" language can be removed to an appendix, or omitted altogether.

Comment: Should I add a space between an English phrase/word and a Chinese phrase/word? For example, `这里应该用among而不是between。`,  `这里应该用 among 而不是 between 。` or `这里应该用　among　而不是　between　。`, which is correct?

Comment: You are writing in Chinese, not in English.  I can't answer that question  You should ask it on the "chinese language" site.  If it was the other way round. you would use quote marks:   *In this case you use "其中" instead of "之间"* And English quotes, because the language is English.